# jQuery scrollTop goes to the target then rolls up

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery function scrollTop so when an element with a certain class is clicked your location changes. Here's what I have done:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $(".paginacion").click(function() {
        $(document).scrollTop( $("#galeria").offset().top );  
    });
});
```

I am navigating though a pagination menu which is in the middle of the page and I want to go back to that menu when I use the utility (clicking any element with the pagination class).

When I click any of those elements the page scrolls down for an instant but then scrolls back up.

What's wrong?

Comment: My guess: `.paginacion` is causing that. A total guess, though.

Comment: Try adding `return false` to the end of your function. This should stop the click event. I'm not sure, but this could be a solution

Comment: actually, you could scroll to an element without using jQuery: `<a href="#galeria" class="paginacion"> Go to menu </a>` http://jsfiddle.net/q2yPd/

Answer (score 1):

The `<a>` tag has a default `href` anchoring, which jumps to the target id and changes the URL hash/fragment. Just like @Khanh TO's example on the comment.

But if you are really wanting to handle this with jQuery. A good solution would be to first use `preventDefault()` which cancels the default execution on click event. Then switch to `'window'` instead of `'document'` when setting scrollTop. Both are going to have the same effect but `$(window).scrollTop(value)` is supported by all browsers.

```
$(".paginacion").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(window).scrollTop( $("#galeria").offset().top );  
});
```

If you are also looking to `animate` the scrolling, you just need to replace `$(window).scrollTop()` with:

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#galeria").offset().top});
```

FireFox and IE places the overflow at the html level so in order for `animate(scrollTop)` to work cross-browsers we need to include `'html'`.

See this [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/w3udC/).

Comment: Now it takes me to the anchor, but the page generated with pagination doesn't refresh, it stays in the page where I am clicking the `.paginacion` element.

Comment: Can you show us how the pagination works? add it on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) .

Comment: It is generated with CodeIgniter, it just creates an `<a>` element for every pagination item with the corresponding link.